# Why can't one solve this continued fraction this way?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continued-fractions

I have the following problem:
[image]

The way I solved the problem is by rewriting it as a system of equations:

$$ x = 1 +\frac 1y$$
$$ y = 2 + \frac1y$$
Then I solved it as a normal system of equations and arrived at the answer of $\sqrt2$. But apparently the answer is $e$? How does that make sense? Can someone explain the result to me?

Comment: Can you show us how you solved it?

Comment: That doesn't look like a usual continued fraction for $e$.  What source are you looking at?

Comment: This is equal to $\sqrt{2}$. I don't know where you got this equals $e$ from.

Comment: @Randall, do you mean the system of equations itself? I don't think I made any calculations mistakes as wolfram alpha gives me the same answer for the system of equations, which made me think that there is another, more sophisticated way of solving the problem without the use of systems of equations.

Comment: @PeterForeman I see. I apologise for the inconvenience. The answer is from a book of recreational mathematics. The solution is wrong then. Should I remove the question?

Comment: Continued fraction for $e$ is not periodic

Comment: @Adam Grey:$\;$Out of curiosity, what book?

Comment: @Adam Grey: To solve without a system, consider the continued fraction for $x+1$. Then immediately, you get the equation
$$x+1=2+\frac{1}{x+1}$$
which yields $x=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: $e = [2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,...]$

Comment: @quasi It's a Brazilian Portuguese book called "Matematica Recreativa 3: Anos 16-18", and not a very good one apparently.

Comment: @Adam Grey: The answer key is often done by someone other than the author, so it can be regarded as less reliable than the main text. And in any case, there can always be typos. So I would judge the quality of the text by the quality of the writing style, and the degree to which it inspires you to work through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, $e$ is not so good looking at continued fractions... Indeed $$e=[2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,\ldots]$$You have found a correct answer, yes! $x=\sqrt{2}$ is the correct number with the given continued fraction.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks for noting, it was a small typo...

Comment: @PeterForeman Woah! Didn't know earlier... Thanks :)